# how to have pdf links on chrome browsers without being blocked?

Tags: php, html, google-chrome, pdf, web

We have a website that chrome is blocking pdfs which have been written with href="x.pdf", I have been researching and saw that we have to change the header of the page to become pdf by Content-Disposition , another solution was to have the pdfs on an iframe.

I was wondering what is the best way to have pdfs which can be read by all browsers without any issues, for example iframe might not be a good solution for SEO purposes, or changing a header on server side might not be very applicable.

I would be glad to know your thoughts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you wrote it like `<a href="x.pdf" download>Link Text</a>` it would allow the pdf to be downloaded so the viewer can then chose how to read it. This should work on all browsers. Hope this helps.